# How to style the ticks based on our requirements in chart js?

Tags: css, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2vy0nvh/136/)
I have the graph like above. There are 2 types of values. Negative and positive values.
I am using angular chart js here.
i)In X axes i want the negative values of the fonts to be in one color and positive values in another color in the same X axes and zero should be in one color.i.e the negative values in green color and positive values in red and zero in black. 
ii)  I need the space between y axis ticks and graph.
iii) How to align the text in y axis. i.e here The Y ticks values are right aligned. i need it to be left aligned.
iv) Is that possible to give box-shadow for the x-axes ticks

Can anyone please help me on this.

```
var ctx = $("#graphTest").get(0).getContext("2d");


var options = {
  barShowStroke: false,
  scaleBeginAtZero : false,
  scaleOverride: true,
  scaleSteps: 20,
  scaleStepWidth: 2,
  scaleStartValue: -20,
  responsive: true,
  barBeginAtOrigin: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
        {
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                fontColor : 'red',
                callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                    console.log(label+" "+index+ " "+labels);
                    return label < 0 ? label * -1 : label;
                }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: '1k = 1000'
            }
        }
    ],
  yAxes: [{
    stacked: true
  }]
}
};

 var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",      "July"],
datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [-65, 59, 80, -81, 56, 55, 40],
    },

     {
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [10, -59, -80, 81, -56, -55, -40],
    }
   ]
 };


var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: data,
   options: options
 });
```